# alogrithim possible values java sudoku

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, sudoku

Where am I going wrong? This doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to specify in the parameter an i and j which locates the cell. And returns the possible values in a 9 x 9 sudoku grid. 
What this does it that the first array i.e a[0]= true if the cell is empty and false if its being played or occupied.
the rest of the array consists of values which are possible values that can be inserted into that i and j cell. therefore a possible value is 4 then it will return a[4]= true and the rest of the boolean array would be possible. can anyone tel me where I'm going wrong? Is the while loop incorrect?

```
   public boolean[] getPossible( int i, int j)
   {

    final int booArraySize = 10;
    boolean[] possibleArray = new boolean[booArraySize];
    int zero = 0;
    if ( game[i][j] == 0)
    {

        for( int b=1; b < possibleArray.length; b++)
        {
            possibleArray[b] = true;
        }

        int row=i;
        int col= 0;

        int[] copyy = new int[GRID_SIZE];
        for( int m = 0; m < copyy.length; m++)
        {
            copyy[m] = 1;
        }

        while ( (copyy[0] < 10) && (copyy[0] >0))
        {
            for ( int q= col+1; q < game.length; q++)
            {
                if( copyy[0] == game[row][q])
                {
                    possibleArray[q] = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    possibleArray[q] = possibleArray[q];
                }
            }
            copyy[0] = copyy[0] + 1;

        }
         possibleArray[0]= true;
    }

    return possibleArray;
}
```

Comment: what does the game datastructure represent?

Comment: The first strange thing in the ode is that you're always using `copyy[0]` and never any other elements of that array.
The second thing is that `possibleArray[q]` gets set to true whenever a cell in the same column doesn't contain `copyy[0]` so basically, unless **every** cell in that column is 4, 4 will be possible.

Comment: I'm assuming that `game` is a 2D array of the sudoku board containing the numbers in the cells, 0 meaning blank.

Comment: yes but i am incrementing the copy[0] eleement by one at the end so it can check all the values from 1 to 9 and not zero.

Comment: So what is "wrong" right now: are you getting that all the numbers are possible even when some aren't?

Comment: yeah all of them seem to be true and the last element in the array seems to be only false

Comment: They are all true because they get set to true whenever there is any cell in that column that isn't the number (which will always happen). The last one is false because (I'm guessing) `game.length` = 9? so `q` goes from 1 to 8. You never touch `possibleArray[9]`.

Comment: how can is possibly fix that? yep the length is9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you are trying to set `possibleArray` to be `true` at positions corresponding to allowed values. You seem to be scanning the game board and doing some testing in order to decide when to set each index position to `true`. I would suggest you reverse your logic: set `possibleArray` to `true` for all values and then scan the board for values that would rule out particular values. You can do that by using the value of the game board at each position relevant to (i, j) as an index to set `possibleArray` to `false`, as in this pseudocode:

```
// initialize possibleArray to true at all positions
for (each board position u,v along row i, column j, and square containing (i,j)) {
    possibleArray[game[u][v]] = false;
}
possibleArray[0] = true; // do this after instead of before
```

For empty game positions, this will set possibleArray[0] to false, but you fix that after the loop exits.

EDIT:

Here's my attempt to deal with rows and columns simultaneously. It doesn't deal with the 3x3 box containing position (i,j); that's left as an exercise. :)

```
public boolean[] getPossible( int i, int j)
   {

    boolean[] possibleArray = new boolean[10];
    if (game[i][j] == 0)
    {
        for( int b=1; b < 10; b++)
        {
            possibleArray[b] = true;
        }

        for (int n = 1; n < GRID_SIZE; ++n) {
            possibleArray[game[i][n]] = possibleArray[game[n][j]] = false;
        }
        // TODO Scan the 3x3 square containing cell (i,j)
        possibleArray[0]= true;
    }
    return possibleArray;
}
```

I assume (based on your code) that game[1][1] through game[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE] are the right index range for the game board.

Comment: it is giving me true and false now but they dont seem to be right if as if say 8 is already present within that row, then it returns true for a[8]= true rather then false. queit strange

Comment: You are iterating in one dimension across the game board. Don't you need to iterate in both (to check both along the row and along the column)?

Comment: yes but i thought i can do it spereately,first row and then column.

Comment: It's probably easier to do both row and column together. I've posted some code.

Comment: yes thanks very much its working. ill try doing the sub grids:D